# Bundler.require does not work for ActiveRecord in my gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I just created a new gem (using bundler) and want to add Active Record support. So I added `s.add_dependency "activerecord", "~> 3.0"` to my gemspec. Then I use Bundler.setup and Bundler.require and thought that I have access to Active Record now, but I haven't. I have to explicitly use `require "active_record"`. Any idea why Bundler.require does not work for me in that case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Firstly, if you're packaging a gem, [do not use `Bundler.require`](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/issue/905#issue/905/comment/616802). `Bundler.require` is for apps not gems.

- In `.gemspec`, specify the dependencies of your deployed gem.
- In your `Gemfile`, include the line `gemspec` to automatically include the dependencies listed in your `.gemspec` in your `Gemfile`.

  You may also optionally create gem groups for dev and test.
- In your code, explicitly `require` any libraries you need.

I lost a couple of hours on this today so I hope this helps.

(Sources [[1](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/issue/905#issue/905/comment/616802)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127692/using-bundler-inside-my-gem/4143399#4143399), [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127692/using-bundler-inside-my-gem/4143399#4143399)](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/bundler-because-your-gems-depend-on-gems-too/))

Secondly, though the ActiveRecord gem is called "activerecord", the lib is called "active_record". This is what you would need in `Gemfile`.

```
gem 'activerecord', :require => "active_record"
```

Unless you include the `:require` option, ActiveRecord won't be loaded correctly and you won't know about it until you try to use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want use Bundler you need define your Gemfile with Activerecord

```
gem 'activerecord', "~> 3.0.0"
```

Or you need define bundler to use your gemspec with adding gemspec in your Gemfile

```
gemspec
```

See http://gembundler.com/rubygems.html

Comment: There is already gemspec in my Gemfile (bundler does that automatically for newly created gems), so that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and the issue in my case was that I was naming a directory in my gem active record, as in:

```
lib ->
  active_record ->
    base.rb <- containing some monkey patches to base
```

This was causing mass confusion including sweet error messages like:

```
Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Base
Did you mean?  ActiveRecord::Base
```

Simply moving changing the file from `lib/active_record/base.rb` to `lib/active_record_base.rb` fixed it for me.